# Adding an AND operator into an FFmpeg command for both an MP3 and OGG lookup functionality

Tags: audio, ffmpeg, playlist

Using Linux Mint I've been using the following code successfully to generate an m3u playlist file of all musical tracks in a given folder. That's fine for instances where the whole contents are Ogg's; and I change the listed extension within the code to mp3 in the instance I'm working from a folder full of mp3's:

```
`playlist='play.m3u' ; if [ -f $playlist ]; then rm $playlist ; fi ; for f in *.ogg; do echo "$f" >> "$playlist"; done`
```

It would be very beneficial if I could add an AND operator in the above so that the generated text file will list both MP3 files and Oggs together in the same list/generated file. Can anyone tell me how to do this please?

I attempted to include:

...`for f in *.ogg AND '.mp3';`

and

...`for f in *.ogg & '.mp3';

and

...`for f in *.ogg && '.mp3';

None of which worked.

Comment: `for f in *.{ogg,mp3}`?

Comment: I'm unable to tick the comment by fdcpp; but it worked! Thank you very much.

Comment: What is worth noting is that this is not an ffmpeg question but rather a bash/unix shell question. If you could, write up an answer that runs through your thinking and it is possible it will be useful to someone else in the future. You know the answer now, but you previously did not. Write the answer you _wish_ your post self had found when confronted with this by problem.

Answer (score 1):

I owe another user the answer to this problem but it is now solved.

In order to include multiple file extensions when generating a m3u music playlist, you simply add brackets and a comma to separate the different extensions you may encounter within a particular folder.

Below is an example where you wish to generate an m3u playlist within a folder that includes a mix of Mp3's, Ogg's and WAV's:

```
playlist='play.m3u' ; if [ -f $playlist ]; then rm $playlist ; fi ; for f in *.{mp3,ogg,wav}; do echo "$f" >> "$playlist"; done
```

The order in which you place the file extensions within the command determines the order in which those files will appear in the generated m3u file; so in the example above, Mp3 files will be listed first followed by Ogg's and then finally Wav's. Each extension will also be sorted alphanumerically.

'play.m3u' can obviously be substituted for whatever title you'd like to give the m3u file.